# How to read large size pickle file with chunks?

Tags: python, pickle

As far as I know...

- CSV has chunk size(pandas)
- Excel has skiprows(pandas)
- Parquet has chunksize(dask)

But pickle has no chunk and skiprows

I want to split data size when I 'read' the file (cause this might not cause a memory error when files are too large) not after loaded.

I have code in mind that I found on Stack Overflow but is this the right code for my question? I don't know if it's splitting files when upload not after the uploading.

```
import pickle

filename = "./pickle.pickle"
str_to_save = "myname"

with open(filename,'wb') as file_handle:
    pickle.dump(str_to_save[0:4], file_handle)
    pickle.dump(str_to_save[4:], file_handle)
    
with open(filename,'rb') as file_handle:
    result = pickle.load(file_handle)
    print('result1:',result)
    result = pickle.load(file_handle)
    print('result2:',result)
```

Comment: can you save your file in a more useful format to you such as parquet?

Comment: I have to return the various extension files with sampled size(lower than 1G) for users so.. saving files is not my job

Comment: No, how is this evens supposed to work? `pickle` is a serialization format for arbitrary python objects. What would a "chunk" even be? parquet and csv are tabular, record-based formats. So a "chunk" is just some number of rows, that has a natural meaning. That doesn't apply to a generic python object

Comment: oh.. so if I want to return small size of pickle file, do I have to compress file? not split ? now I'm just worried about memory error of large picklefile.,.

Comment: @sim no, compression wouldn't help because that would only affect *disk space*, not how much RAM would be required. Again, the only thing you can do with pickle is *load the entire object*. Note, in a pickle file, you can `dump` multiple objects and read those objects one at a time, but that depends on the pickle file being written that way, where essentially you have multiple pickles in the same file. You haven't  given us any details about what you are working with. But the answer to your question is "no, you can't reach a pickle in chunks" because that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: maybe my explanation was not enough to explain this problem, as far as I know the pandas.read_extenstions provides turning various extension files to dataframe and while loading the file , they also provide chunk funtions for changed dataframe ,, so I was wondering if there's any APIs or ways to provide these same funtions